# How to find user with exact username with kcadm?

Tags: keycloak

I am using keycloak v19.0.1. I have a problem with using kcadm.sh to find an user with exact username.

E.g. I have 3 users: user1, user11, user12

```
> kcadm get users -r myrealm -q username=user1
```

The command returns all three users. I would like the command to return only the user1.
So far the option -q use wildcards.

```
> kcadm help get

Get all users whose 'username' matches '*test*' pattern, and 'email' matches '*@google.com*':
$ kcadm.sh get users -r demorealm -q username=test -q email=@google.com
```

I have found a similar question [Keycloak - How to check if username and email exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52726048/keycloak-how-to-check-if-username-and-email-exists). The keycloak console works pretty well with double quotes for  exact words searching at page Users. I wonder if i can do the same thing with kcadm.

I have tried using single and double quotes, both commands returns 3 results as without using any quotes.

```
> kcadm get users -r myrealm -q username='user1'
> kcadm get users -r myrealm -q username="user1"
```

By the doc https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/19.0.1/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource
REST API: **GET /{realm}/users**, there is a boolean parameter called ***exact***

```
which defines whether the params "last", "first", "email" and "username" must match exactly
```

Does the same feature available in kcadm.sh?

Comment: I bet use of quotes might help.
As in :
username='user1'

Comment: I tried single and double quotes, both do not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You needs to place `-q exact=true` before `-q username=user1`

```
> kcadm get users -r myrealm -q exact=true -q username=user1
```

So `-q` option order is matter

I tested in docker container in v19.0.3 (legacy) with Git-bash on windows 11

```
$ winpty docker exec -it [<Keycloak CONTAINER ID>] bash
```

[image]

Go bin directory

```
cd /opt/jboss/keycloak/bin
```

[image]

I create 10 users in `example` realm.
[image]

If will query by `user1`, the `other-user1` and `user1` will returned without `exact` true.

Configure for connection

```
./kcadm.sh config credentials --server http://localhost:8080/auth --realm master --user admin --password admin
```

Search user without `exact` option.

```
./kcadm.sh get users -r example -q username=user1
```

[image]

Search user with `exact` is true option.

```
./kcadm.sh get users -r example -q exact=true -q username=user1
```

[image]

But if switch order `username` first then `exact` later, won't work. It will return two users.

```
./kcadm.sh get users -r example -q username=user1 -q exact=true
```

##### Update, How I know this syntax?

#1 In [API spec](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/19.0.1/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource), I found the `exact` is `Key`
from this statements ("username" must match exactly).

[image]

#2 confirmed by Postman.
Query params is add `&KEY=value` format.
so I added this query at the end of existing URL.

```
&exact=true
```

[image]

#3 Last one is how to add query in kcadm.

In the Keycloak [Admin Cli](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/main/server_admin/topics/admin-cli.adoc) documentation, `You can filter across multiple attributes by specifying multiple -q options.`. So I found `-q`  is query option and `multiple` statement can do. I added `-q exact=true`. The order is found experiment in docker container terminal.

[image]

Comment: Very impressive. Thanks for the API link.

Comment: Thanks your wake up morning, I totally  forgot kc command can do user management easley.